# Getting a working remote desktop server running on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, terminal-server, xdmcp

OK - here is something that I have had working a ton of times in the past - an XDMCP enabled X server that serves nice and shiny sessions including a login handler.

What I have:

- A virtual Ubuntu machine running on ESXi - I want this machine to be a like a Windows Terminal Server.
- A working VNC setup via `x11vnc` - this is OK if you have a running sesion, but not if you want to login and create a new session. Also - quite messy on a multi user box
- A lot of experiments with `lightdm` and `gdm`, trying to get the `XDMCP`functionality up and running. Editing `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and `/etc/gdm/*` is working to some extent. I can get the login manager running via lightdm, but once logged in, the user is just left hanging with no session to play with.

In `lightdm` (which is where I am at right now), my `lightdm.conf` has this:

```
[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest=false
[XDMCPServer]
enabled=true
port=177
```

There are some things here I think I am just not getting - this is where I'd like some really super answers:

- XDMCP still lives (via SSH or not) even though it is sort of old and grey. Is there something new (like a new protocol) I don't know about that I should be using instead?
- Is the user base for this sort of thing shrinking and should I be employing a different strategy? I really don't want to because I like terminal servers.

And - this is of course the answer I am really looking for:

- Can someone point me to the exact spots in the `gdm` or `lightdm` config files that need to be changed in an otherwise completely default Ubuntu 14.04.2 Desktop edition (64 bit)?

I realize there are projects like LTSP out there, but this is not what I want, since I don't want my clients to boot into a Ubuntu setup or anything - they just need to be able to log in same as if they were using Remote Desktop to start a Windows session. I am really feeling quite dejected at this point - I had this working super smooth ten years ago, but now a working solution completely eludes me.

Comment: Have you looked at `xrdp`? I've used a few times, it works pretty much like you described.

Comment: I think this is probably what I want! Can't seen how I missed it but I guess being XDMCP / VNC focused threw my Google-Fu off. I will test this and comment later. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - so I figured it out finally. As @gnur suggests, `xrdp` is the thing to use, but not right out of the box. It appears that the XRDP that comes with Ubuntu is old(ish), so:

- XRDP must be built from source. Get the source [here](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/tree/master) and follow the very nice manual [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=4242) to get things in reasonably working order. Without this, session reconnection does not work which is a bit of a show stopper.

I have done a couple of extras to get things completely in shape:

- XRDP does not work as other X things do with `xmodmap`, so if you keyboard is not working as you want it to in an XRDP session, you have to:

  - Log on to a real console session (i.e. not via XRDP, but maybe via the ESXi console or physically) and adapt things to your keyboard layout in that session. Try `setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout <your-layout>` (`dk` in my case)
  - Then dump the working layout to an `.ini` file that XRDP can load. Do this: `xrdp-genkeymap mymap.ini`
  - Figure out what to actually name the file by looking at `/var/log/xrdp.log` look for something like `local keymap file for 0x0406 found`. Then name your file `/etc/xrdp/km-0406.ini`. That took a while to figure out.
- Modify your `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`so you have a session description that looks like this:

  `[xrdp1]
  name=sesman-Xvnc
  lib=libvnc.so
  username=ask
  password=ask
  ip=127.0.0.1
  port=-1
  delay_ms=2000`

  The key parts are `lib` and `delay_ms` - without the delay, I got no desktop after logging in to an XRDP session. It seems the underlying VNC session takes a little while to get ready and if connections are attempted too soon, you get nothing.
- Put something sensible in your `~/.xsession` file. I have `xfce4-session` but that came with another oddity - tab completion in terminal windows did not work. Apparently, XFCE uses the tab key for window switching. To fix this, you need to edit (maybe there is a GUI thing too) `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` and apply the fix described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418831/command-line-auto-complete-tab-key-not-work-in-terminal-for-ubuntu).

That is it! With this running, I have a very nice replacement for XDMCP that lets users treat Ubuntu sessions as they do Windows sessions. Just as I wanted :-)

**EDIT**
having used this a while, I have found the solution to be workable but not that stable. From time to time, the session reconnection will not work and users will be left in a limbo state, unable to log on at all. Restarting the services fixes this, but it doesn't really hold up.

So - I looked some more for a working solution - and found one! My new best friend is [x2go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/start), which is a standalone X server with a special client package that comes in several OS flavors.

**EDIT 2:**
OK - so even more about this. I found that while X2go is quite nice, the Windows client has a quirk that pretty much stops it from working with key based SSH logins, so I have had to enable regular PW logins for my desktop host. Not optimal, but it does not change the fact that X2go works really well in all other respects.

**EDIT 3:**
Scarygliders has a very nice script at this point that gets, compiles and installs everything needed for a shiny RDP session setup. I pretty much eliminates the need for the other stuff I found. Get the scripts [here](https://github.com/scarygliders/X11RDP-o-Matic) by cloning. Then run `X11rdp-o-matic.sh --justdoit`. I now have a desktop host that services five users all doing Python development and such. Very nice.